# Passing command line arguments in python

Tags: python

How can I pass command line arguments that are not positional. I just want to pass arguments that I can assign to specific variables in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import argparse. : [for Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html)

[For python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html)

You can call the script below like so:

> python myScript.py -showGivenNumber 42

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-showGivenNumber', action="store", dest="givennumber",)
myArgs =  parser.parse_args()
print( myArgs.givennumber )
```

Here we define the ArgumentParser as parser and add the argument -showGivenNumber, which we print out.

Comment: Good to hear. The lib is very good and I am sure it have a use case for all your needs with regards to arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Bash reads the arguments as strings, you can write the string to contain identifying info.

```
$python3 myscript.py second:two first:one third fourth
```

then the script needs to figure out what goes where:

```
import sys


args={'generic':[]}
for arg in sys.argv[1:]: #gets the arguments from bash as a list of strings
    if ':' not in arg:args['generic'].append(arg) #collects generic args
    else: #contains an arbitrary key seperator
        key,val=arg.split(':')
        assert key not in args #raises an error if its going to overwrite a key
        args[key]=val



main_program(**vars)
```

In the main_program function, first and second will be variables you can work with and 'generic' will have a list containing third and fourth, etc.

The keys must be valid python variables or calling program will raise an type error before calling the main_program.